# MYSQL Query and Chart.js and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

Hoping for some help.

I have data in a MYSQL database containing a listing of computers in the company. One of the fields is the date a computer was purchased, another is the brand.

I want to create a bar chart using Chart.js showing the amount of computers we have for each distinct year. So on the X axis we have all the distinct years as labels and on the Y axis we have the count of all the computers purchased in each one of the years.

I have written this code but can not get it to work:

The Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(purchased) AS years, COUNT(brand) AS 'count' FROM computers GROUP BY purchased, brand ORDER BY purchased";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


        $years = array();
        $count = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $years[]  = $row["years"];
            $count[] = $row["count"];
        }    
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Then the chart:

```
<script>


    var barChartData = {
        labels : <?php=json_encode($years);?>,
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : <?php=json_encode($count);?>
            }       ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                ctx.canvas.height = 200;
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
```

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong. Have struggled to get this to chart.

Thank you.

Comment: what does the following line look like `labels : <?php=json_encode($years);?>,` when its on your page? can you provide the data there ... I'm thinking its formatted wrong

Comment: indeed. json_encode will give back an object like an array. There is no way charts.js can read that without further specification.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is set to json_encode, this is not how chart.js can read it.

Change your code from:

```
<?php=json_encode($count);?>
```

To:

```
["<?php echo implode('","',$count);?>"]
```

And for the years, from:

```
<?php=json_encode($years);?>
```

to:

```
["<?php echo implode('","',$years);?>"]
```

The quotes are there to contain anything the isn't a numerical value, if your positive that all data is numerical, you can remove them, but since it doesn't hurt to have them, I've included them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestino but that did not work. The chart now just shows two labels: <?php=implode(' and ';$years);?>. Blank otherwise. I tried removing the quotes from the strings and then nothing shows on the chart nor labels.

Comment: Also tried: <?php echo '['.implode(", ", $years).']'?> and <?php echo '['.implode(", ", $count).']'?> but they did not work as well.

Comment: I edited the answer to use echo, instead of =. When you changed it to echo, did you get the right output? You may need to see if years and count are being populated. I also notice you don't have the 2 double quotes inside your bracket for your second comment. Try the new code I just edited.

Comment: OK - I placed your code in and the chart now renders but no data shows. Just the X and Y axis lines. I believe the issue must be with the query. I have been trying different approaches but none seem to work. The latest try is this query SELECT year(purchased) as years, COUNT(id) as count FROM computers GROUP BY purchased ORDER BY purchased but I do not think my code to place the data into the array's is working.

Comment: Does your query output in the mysql editor properly? if you can give me a raw output of the mysql query, I can check it against your code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out:

1: Used this query:

SELECT YEAR(purchased) as years, COUNT(ID) as count FROM computers GROUP BY years

2: Had a TYPO! while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) should had been:

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)). I forgot the i in mysql_fetch!

Along with the great help from Greg it is working great now.

Thanks for the help!